# Ellipticity of an unbounded operator $L$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplacian, elliptic-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $L$ be an unbounded operator, such that
$$L = \operatorname{div} \left( M \nabla_{x}\right),$$
where $M$ is a non-degenerate symmetric $n\times n$-matrix ($ \det M\neq 0$) and $\nabla_{x}$ is the gradient vector on $\mathbb R^n$, i.e.,
$$\nabla_{x}= \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{1}},\dots,\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{n}}\right)^t .$$
What can we say about the ellipticity of the operator $L$?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the definition?

Comment: Here ([Elliptic operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator)) there is the definition. I.e., its principle symbol $\sigma(x,\xi)$ does not vanish, for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\xi\in \mathbb R^n-\{0\}$. But, it is difficult to apply.

Comment: Actually example 2 in the link answers your question.

Comment: @ John Ma, in the link, the matrix $M$ is symmetric and positive definite. But, in my case, it is, just, symmetric non-degenerate?

Comment: Yes, that's actually equivalent.

Comment: i.e., positive definite equivalent to non-degenerate?